# Is it bad practice to call an optional function inside didSet of a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, functional-programming

I have been looking for an easy way to automatically update UI when a variable is updated. Regular KVO is so much messy code, so I've been looking at RxSwift, ReactiveCocoa etc., but found these to be hard to grasp, and a lot of new objects and just too much stuff I don't need.

I have been playing around with a variable's `didSet`, together with an emtpy optional function in my object. Hopefully it's easier to show than to explain:

A custom object (a viewModel)

```
class AwesomeViewModel{
    var awesomeText:String { didSet { updateBlock?() } }
    var updateBlock:(()->())?

    init(awesomeText:String){
        self.awesomeText = awesomeText
    }
}
```

And a custom UIView:

```
class AwesomeView:UIView{
    @IBOutlet weak var awesomeLabel: UILabel!

    func bindViewModel(viewModel:AwesomeViewModel){
        viewModel.updateBlock = { [weak self] in
            self?.awesomeLabel.text = viewModel.awesomeText
        }
        viewModel.updateBlock?()
    }
}
```

Let's say this custom view `AwesomeView` exists in a `UIViewController` as an outlet.
I create an instance of `AwesomeViewModel`, and then call `self.awesomeView.bindViewModel(awesomeViewModel)`.

When I later, in my `UIViewController` (or anywhere else, for that matter, it can be passed around) do something like `awesomeViewModel.awesomeText = "Hello World"`, then the viewModel's variable's didSet will trigger the optional function `updateBlock`. Since this function has been set by the custom view `AwesomeView`, it will automatically update the text in the label in that view.

I thought this was pretty cool, and easy to understand, but are there any side effects of this, or something I'm not seeing? Is it bad practice? It seems so much easier than using the standard KVO with all the functions and observing etc..

I was thinking of using this for `UITableViewCell`'s, where the `bindViewModel()` would be called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I don't think there are any retain cycles or anything, but I'm not that good at spotting them..

I was hoping to get some pros and cons about this method before I apply it to my app - only to find out it's the stupidest idea in the world. But to me it seems ok.

Comment: The biggest drawback compared to KVO is that it's not granular at all (which may be fine for your own needs). If your model has several properties and one "updateBlock" then you never know what was actually updated, just that something was updated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe learning RxSwift is a good idea. However in the meantime, what you're doing is mostly fine. A limitation of this approach is that you are limited to only one callback; RxSwift would allow an arbitrary number of subscriptions to one Observable. I apologize in advance that this answer is fairly opinion-based.

I would change the `updateBlock` to have the "observed" value as a parameter, i.e.

```
var updateBlock: ((String) -> ())?
```

As this could help avoid retain cycles, and perhaps rename `updateBlock` to more accurately reflect *which* value has changed, i.e.

```
var awesomeTextUpdate: ((String) -> ())?
```

However, @rmaddy is right, this becomes a pain with multiple properties that you may wish to observe. This can be partially-solved with an enum of properties and their values, e.g.

```
class AwesomeViewModel {
  enum Property {
    case awesomeText(String)
    case awesomeNumber(Int)
  }
}
```

and changing the `updateBlock` to have the type

```
var updateBlock: ((AwesomeViewModel.Property) -> ())?
```

and the `didSet` to

```
var awesomeText: String { 
  didSet {
    updateBlock?(.awesomeText(awesomeText))
  }
}
```

Then clients can simply `switch` on the `Property` enum; break where they don't care and access where they do. This can become a pain if you have many potentially-observable properties but the client only needs a single one in a particular case.

If it seems like there's no correct compromise it's mostly because there isn't and RxSwift might be the better long-term solution. However, if you won't be widely replicating this paradigm, an optional function is fine. Remember: Don't Repeat Yourself.

tl;dr what you're doing looks reasonable, but doesn't scale well.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. Yeah, the point @rmaddy really hit me. UI would update three unnecessary times if I updated four variables, that's not acceptable.. I am now thinking about keeping an extra variable in all ViewModels, e.g a bool named "needsUpdate", which is the only variable with a `didSet`, that calls the updateBlock if this bool was set to `true`. Every time I update a variable, I would have to set this bool to `true`, and the block would be called, and inside the block I would have to set the bool back to `false`.. Unnecessary UI updates might occur, but only once for each update..